# Scala: Return an instance of the passed-in type

Tags: scala, reflection, types, polymorphism

I am trying to implement a simple validator method that would take
a type as its first parameter and a String as the second and would always return an instance of the passed-in type. Without no further ado - this is the method:

```
def validateType[T](taip: T, input: String):T = taip match {
    case Boolean => {
      val simplifiedInput = input.replaceAll("[ \\n]", "").toLowerCase()
      if(simplifiedInput.matches("[yn]")){
        simplifiedInput match {
          case "y" => true
          case "n" => false
        }  
      } else{
        validateType(Boolean, StdIn.readLine("$simplifiedInput is not a valid "
      +"answer, please try again"))
      }
    }
  }
```

However I get a compile error (red underscore in my IDE) saying:
"type mismatch; Found Boolean(true) required : T

I realize that `T` here is a `type`, but how can I specify that I want to return an instance of that type? I tried to play with the ClassTag also but with no success. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want a behavior for a given type, and not a given object or value, a typeclass would be relevant.

```
trait Validable[T] {
  def validate(input: String): T
}

object Validable {
  implicit val boolean = new Validable[Boolean] {
    def validate(input: String): Boolean = {
      val simplifiedInput = input.replaceAll("[ \\n]", "").toLowerCase()
      if(simplifiedInput.matches("[yn]")){
        simplifiedInput match {
          case "y" => true
          case "n" => false
        }  
      } else {
        validate(StdIn.readLine("$simplifiedInput is not a valid "
        +"answer, please try again"))
    }
  }
  //if you want to write a validator for another type, simply add a new instance.
  implicit val otherTypeValidable = new Validable[OtherType] {
    def validate(input: String): OtherType = ...  
  }
}

def validateType[T](input: String)(implicit validable: Validable[T]): T =
  validable.validate(input)
validateType[Boolean]("y") // returns true
```

Of course, you can implement an instance for your typeclass for each relevant type. This will throw a compilation error if you use it with a type for which you do not have an implicit instance of `Validable[T]`, so it is safer than using reflection.

Comment: That's very interesting! The inner `def validate` is a recursive method, so in order to compile its return type must be `Boolean` ?  And I would have to declare an implicit for any new return type?

Comment: Yes exactly. Sorry about the forgotten return type.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrille Corpet. I am changing the right answer to this one, because this not only compiles but also yields the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [TypeTag](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) for this, like:

```
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  def validateType[T](input: String)(implicit typeTag: TypeTag[T]): T = {
    typeTag.tpe match {
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Boolean] => {
        val simplifiedInput = input.replaceAll("[ \\n]", "").toLowerCase()
        if (simplifiedInput.matches("[yn]")) {
          simplifiedInput match {
            case "y" => true.asInstanceOf[T]
            case "n" => false.asInstanceOf[T]
          }
        } else {
          validateType(StdIn.readLine("$simplifiedInput is not a valid "
            + "answer, please try again"))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  validateType[Boolean]("y") //set Boolean type for `T`
  >true
```

In there `=:=` used to test whether `Type` is equal. more comparator see the reference. and for the **return type** to `T`, you need **cast** it by `asInstanceOf[T]`.

Comment: Thanks chengpohi! The typeTag is an implicit, and the first argument (the client specified type) is gone so how is this line `t =:= typeOf[Boolean]` going to determine that "[yn]" is of type Boolean?

Comment: @vasigorc, you can use it as `validateType[Boolean]("y")`, In there, set the generic type `Boolean` for `T`.

Comment: `ClassTag` is not deprecated, you are confusing it with `Manifest`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, Thanks clarify.`// @deprecated("use scala.reflect.ClassTag (to capture erasures) or scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag (to capture types) or both instead", "2.10.0")
trait Manifest[T] extends ClassManifest[T]`

Comment: Hello @chengpohi, I am giving the right answer to Cyrille. Your approach does eliminate the compilation errors, but in case of a correct input ([YyNn]) the program terminates unexpectedly.